# Trouble stopping animation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to make kind of typewriting effect in HTML5.
For rendering and puting it all together , I'm using this [pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) plugin.

So far I have been able to make it work (partially), although it seems that the `update()` method that is responsible for updating the text inside my `PIXI.TEXT` object is not willing to stop the animation interval.

Please see more below.

**RPGtext.js**

```
define(['pixi', 'jquery'], function (PIXI, $){
    var RPGText = (function(text, style,  pos) 
    {
        var self = this; 
        var default_style =  {
            font : 'bold 36px Arial',
            fill : '#FFF',
            stroke : '#4a1850',
            strokeThickness : 5,
            dropShadow : true,
            dropShadowColor : '#000000',
            dropShadowAngle : Math.PI / 6,
            dropShadowDistance : 6,
            wordWrap : true,
            wordWrapWidth : 440
        };

        var config = {
            update_interval : 30 //// Miliseconds ////
        };

        self.cur_pos = 1;

        var _construct = function(){
            var font_style = $.extend({}, default_style, style);
            _init(font_style);
        };

        var _init = function(font_style){
            self.model = new PIXI.Text(text.substring(0, config.cur_pos), font_style);
            self.model.x =  pos.x;
            self.model.y = pos.y;
            update(self.cur_pos, (text.length - 1) );
        };

        var update = function (x, y) {
            if( self.cur_pos <= text.length){ //// this condition is not making it all stop for some reason /// 
                requestAnimationFrame(update);
                self.cur_pos  = (self.cur_pos + 1);
                self.model.text = text.substring(0, config.cur_pos);
            }else{
                console.log("Stopping"); /// IS nto triggered at all..///
            }
        };

        _construct();

        return self.model;
    });

    return RPGText;
});
```

//// This is how it's being initialized / used ///

**MsgBozx.js**

```
....
    var text = new RPGText(msg.text, config.font.text.style, config.font.text.pos);

    msgbox.addChild(text);

...
```

I have tested the outputs of both `self.cur_pos` and `text.length` (using console.info()). both were showing expected results, though the update never stopped.

Any ideas as what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think there was missing `requestAnimationFrame()` somewhere in my code or there must have been something stored in cache that caused the weird behavior. As today when i ran the code, everything was working perfectly.

Though I have also changed the way of updating the text (see the below jfidle example).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myabnd41/7/)